# is there verse in the Holy Quran, Which refer/indicate to the Lesbian?

Tags: quran, sex, verses

**I believe that Lesbian/Gay both Illegal/Haram in Islam…**

Actually I am looking for verse about **Lesbian**

**would someone can mention any verse about Lesbian ?**

I found two verse about Gay...

**Reference One**

And [We had sent] Lot when he said to his people, "Do you commit such immorality as no one has preceded you with from among the worlds?

Indeed, you approach men with desire, instead of women. Rather, you are a transgressing people."

[Surah Al-A'raf Verse 80-81](https://qurano.com/en/7-al-a-raf/verse-80/)

**Reference Two**

Do you approach males among the worlds?

And leave what your Lord has created for you as mates? But you are a people transgressing."

[Surah Ash-Shu'ara Verse 165-166](https://qurano.com/en/26-ash-shu-ara/verse-165/)

Answer (score 1):

It is my advice to you not to read articles by people who have no qualifications in Islam and are not scholars or people of knowledge in any way.

The Quran does not directly mention the prohibition of these actions between two women in exclusion to the general statement. Meaning, it is  already present in the general verses of the Prophet Lut (AS), but is not mentioned by itself:

> "Do you approach males among the worlds?
>
> "And leave what your Lord has created for you as mates? But you are a people transgressing.

Note how Lut (AS) criticizes their leaving of what Allah created for them as mates. That applies to all such actions, not just male.

The notion that every single prohibition needs to be mentioned directly in the Quran is ridiculous. Allah does not say directly in the Quran that having intercourse with animals is forbidden. Does that mean it is allowed Astaghfirullah?

Rather, many prohibitions are known by general verses that apply to multiple things. Allah does not need to delve into every specific action.

With regards to the issue of intercourse and marriage, Allah has clearly mentioned what is allowed: a marriage between a man and a woman. Anything outside that is not allowed and prohibited.